# Lindelöf hypotheses for derivatives of zeta

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics, riemann-zeta-function

The Lindelöf hypothesis says that if we have:
$$\zeta(\sigma+iT)=\mathcal O(T^a)$$
Then if one considers $\sigma=1/2$ then $\inf a=0$. Further, from convexity and the functional equation this implies that $a=0$ for $\sigma\geq1/2$ and $a=1/2-\sigma$ for $\sigma<1/2$.

I am interested whether there are any similar estimates of $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial s^n}\zeta(s)$ within the critical strip. If possible, I am interested in $n\leq3$.

Comment: One can apply the Cauchy integral formula around a small loop to get the same estimate for higher derivatives.

Comment: There are the natural/obvious estimates from Cauchy's formulas... I'm not sure what you'd hope might be true beyond that kind of thing. Can you clarify? :)

Comment: @WillSawin and PaulGarrett: we were typing simultaneously...

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory" and "cv.complex-variables". I added these tags now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow

Comment: @WillSawin, PaulGarrett, and co: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for. I originally had some elaborate argument recursively estimating the logarithmic derivative, but its nice to know that there is a more direct method of obtaining Lindelof-like bounds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Lindelöf hypothesis yields the same bound for each derivative of $\zeta(s)$ via Cauchy's formula. Indeed, let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$, $T\in(1,\infty)$, $\varepsilon\in(0,1/2)$. Let $C(\sigma+iT,\varepsilon)$ denote the positively oriented circle $|s-\sigma-iT|=\varepsilon$. Then
$$\zeta^{(n)}(\sigma+iT)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{C(\sigma+iT,\varepsilon)}\frac{\zeta(s)}{(s-\sigma-iT)^{n+1}}ds,$$
and hence by the triangle inequality for complex line integrals,
$$|\zeta^{(n)}(\sigma+iT)|\leq\frac{n!}{\varepsilon^n}\sup_{s\in C(\sigma+iT,\varepsilon)}|\zeta(s)|\ll_{n,\sigma,\varepsilon}T^{\max(0,1/2-\sigma+\varepsilon)+\varepsilon}\leq T^{\max(0,1/2-\sigma)+2\varepsilon}.$$
Comparing the two sides, and replacing $\varepsilon$ by $\varepsilon/2$, we infer for every $\varepsilon>0$ eventually that
$$\zeta^{(n)}(\sigma+iT)\ll_{n,\sigma,\varepsilon}T^{\max(0,1/2-\sigma)+\varepsilon}.$$

Comment: Ah! I can't believe I missed this. Thanks for writing up an answer

Comment: @psubodiosa I am glad I could help.